# Nonlinear Model with ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I have a NLP model (using IPOPT) that's giving the error `ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: t_0` (where `t_0` is a model variable) for several variables in the objective function and constraints. But all variables are initialized, and all sets and parameters are constructed properly. I also checked that the variables with errors do appear in the expressions for the objective function and constraints.

I also get errors such as `ERROR: Variable 't_0' is not part of the model being written out, but appears in an expression used on this model.` for the same variables having the previous error.

Running the debugger, it shows problems in the line containing the `nonlinear_vars` tuple below in file `ampl_.py`:

```
try:
    wrapped_repn = RepnWrapper(
        repn,
        list(self_varID_map[id(var)] for var in linear_vars),
        list(self_varID_map[id(var)] for var in nonlinear_vars))
```

For some reason, the nonlinear variables with errors aren't members of `self_varID_map`.

I can't share the full model here, but am willing to share more details if needed. Just trying to understand why certain variables (not all of them) are giving me those errors, even though they are initialized and used in at least one expression in the model.

**Update 1**

Variable `t_0`, as well as all others with errors, are created and used in the model with expressions similar to the following (everything takes place inside methods of a class, hence the use of `self.`):

```
self._model = AbstractModel(name=self._name)
# Define sets ...
# Define parameters ...
# Define variables
...
t_bounds = (-100.0, 100.0)
...
self._model.t_0 = Var(domain=Reals, bounds=t_bounds)
...
# Instantiate model with given data
...
data_mod = {None: data_mod}
self._model = self._model.create_instance(data=data_mod)
```

And if view the objective function expression, I see `t_0` (and all others) there.

**Update 2**

Here's part of the traceback (at the end, the same error message appears for different variables):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 573, in solve
    self._presolve(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 198, in _presolve
    OptSolver._presolve(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 673, in _presolve
    **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 744, in _convert_problem
    **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\convert.py", line 105, in convert_problem
    problem_files, symbol_map = converter.apply(*tmp, **tmpkw)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\plugins\converter\model.py", line 191, in apply
    io_options=io_options)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\base\block.py", line 1716, in write
    io_options)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\repn\plugins\ampl\ampl_.py", line 378, in __call__
    include_all_variable_bounds=include_all_variable_bounds)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\repn\plugins\ampl\ampl_.py", line 869, in _print_model_NL
    list(self_varID_map[id(var)] for var in nonlinear_vars))
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\repn\plugins\ampl\ampl_.py", line 869, in <genexpr>
    list(self_varID_map[id(var)] for var in nonlinear_vars))
KeyError: (2100849828808, "Variable 't_0' is not part of the model being written out, but appears in an expression used on this model.", "Variable 't_1' ...
```

**Update 3**

Solver call:

```
solver = pyo.SolverFactory(self._solver)
self._solver_status = solver.solve(self._model)
```

where `self._solver` is the string `"ipopt"`.

I only really have one set of constraints. They're defined as follows:

```
I = np.eye(3)

def R_orth_ij(m, i, j):
    return np.dot(self._R.T, self._R)[i, j] == I[i, j]

self._model.R_orth_00 = Constraint(rule=lambda m: R_orth_ij(m, 0, 0))
self._model.R_orth_01 = Constraint(rule=lambda m: R_orth_ij(m, 0, 1))
...
```

where `self._R` is a 3x3 matrix where element `(i,j)` is variable `self.Rij`. Again, I can share the full model if needed.

Comment: Trying to shoot blind here: Did you define your variable as being a part of the model? What is the line where you created your `t_0` variable? Is it part of your model in a way that your variable can be called with `model.t_0`? i.e. `t_0` is created with a line looking like `model.t_0 = Var(...)` or is it just `t_0=Var(...)`?

Comment: Yes, it's added to the model variable. See update 1 above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The fact that you use `self` should not be a problem and I can't see anything wrong in your code. Maybe next thing you can tell us is the line in your own code (not Pyomo) that raises the exception, so maybe it can help us to guess what is the trouble.

Comment: The exception happens in the Pyomo code as I previously mentioned (file `ampl_.py`). See update 2. If this is still not helpful, please let me know how I can share the full model and data (e.g., via e-mail).

Comment: After more debugging, I realized the following. 3 out of the 16 variables appear only in the constraints, not in the objective function (because they are always multiplied by zero in the objective function after instantiating the model). This makes the `Vars_dict` and `nonlinear_vars` data structures not synchronized, resulting in that error in `ampl_.py`. I'm wondering if there's a bug in Pyomo. The 3 variables interact with other variables in the constraints, even though they're not present in the objective function.

Comment: Well, not even artificially adding the missing variables to the objective function worked. I multiplied them by 1E-6, and while that helped to add them to `nonlinear_vars` of the objective function, the `id` of certain variables are still different from those in `self_varID_map` (which is created from `Vars_dict`). So I still get the same error.

Comment: I guess you can post this problem to the Pyomo forum on Google Group. Also, if the problem is in the `ampl_.py` file, it is very hard for me to debug because I am not too much familiar with the inner workings of Pyomo, and I guess I am not the only one here, sorry. Finally, have you tought about making a small example that we could run? i.e. making a model with only the elements that doesn't work (objective function, one or two variables and one or two simple constraints). It doesn't need to produce results, it only needs to produce the bug with the fewest elements as possible. Cheers

Comment: It shouldn't matter that some of your variables don't appear in the objective function. Could you post the lines of code you're using the call IPOPT? Could you also post one of your constraint declarations?

Comment: Please see Update 3. I still suspect something isn't right on my end (not Pyomo), but I really can't figure it out. (Hey, Bethany! :))

Comment: OK, the model wasn't 100% correct, but I think I may have a lead on the culprit. I suspect the `lambda` function in the constraint definition might be causing problems. Not fully convinced of that yet.